# How can I injected a function before call a function?

Tags: php

I have a problem, I cannot call a function before all functions.

I have a parent class - that is a repository.

```
class Repository {

  public function find(/*..*/){/*..*/}
  public function findAll(/*..*/){/*..*/}
  public function findBy(/*..*/){/*..*/}
  public function findA(/*..*/){/*..*/}
  public function findB(/*..*/){/*..*/}

/* then 100+ more public function */

}
```

And I want to create an "Adapter class" that will be calling a function that run before all only public functions BUT I don't want "overwriting" all functions of the parent.

I tried this solution:

```
class OwnRepo extends Repository{

  public __call($methods, $args){/**/}

}
```

BUT the __call method not working with public methods

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

** UPDATE **

Sorry I was not clear!

My controller implements a model, I don't want to change/rewrite the functions of the controllers.

```
class IndexController {

  public function index(){
    $model = new Model(); // will return a OwnRepo object
    $a = model->findAll();
  }

}
```

Comment: An adapter class to do what?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I have updated my question

Comment: From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), you cannot call public methods together with `__call()` as document said _`__call()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context._ So, you need the other way to do that

Comment: From available [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), I don't see any of them that is able to do what you want. (Maybe I'm wrong.) You may have to add code at the beginning of every public methods. For example: `$this->beforeRunMethod()` and inside `beforeRunMethod()` function do your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can't do this with inheritance. You have to check if the desired method exists in the Repository class and then call it.
Try this one:

```
class Repository
{

    public function find($a,$b,$c)
    {
        return "find $a $b $c";
    }
}

class OwnRepo
{
    function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
      
        if (method_exists('Repository', $name)) {
            //some action before
          
            $repo = new Repository();
            $result = call_user_func_array(array($repo, $name), $arguments);

            //some action afterwards
            return $result;
        } else {
            die("Method " . $name . " does not exist");
        }
    }
}

$o = new OwnRepo();
echo $o->find(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Fact Check [The Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I have updated my question

Comment: Sorry, don't understand:
When `$model = new Model()`;  creates an `OwnRepo-Object`, `$model` has all methods of `Repository` because it extends `Repository` and all of it's public methods.

Comment: Yes, right. I want to extend all public function of base repository (exactly I want to run a set logic executing before every public fn calling.)

Comment: So I edited my code example, hoping that helps